# Please I have 24 errors in my tables anyone help?

Tags: undefined, control, sequence

here I paste the screenshot to my error
[image: This is part of my code that doesn't work]

```
\begin{table}[H]
     \centering
     \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
     \begin{tabular}{|cccccccc|}
     \hline
     \multicolumn{8}{|l|}{FORECAST 24H} \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}                                          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Model}                 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Past History} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{MSE}      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{RMSE}     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{MAE}      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{WAPE}     & MAPE     \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{MACHINE LEARNING}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{}{}{LR}}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{24}            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1083220}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{581.6717} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{502.9881} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.026775} & 0.027288 \\ \cline{3-8}
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}                                          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{48}            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{955023.4} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{544.9984} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{463.4439} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.024786} & 0.025514 \\ \cline{3-8} 
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}                                          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{72}            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{902146.3} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{535.9016} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{454.1736} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.024341} & 0.025129 \\ \cline{3-8} 
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}                                          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{96}            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{901062.8} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{534.4753} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{452.8799} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.024281} & 0.025125 \\ \cline{3-8} 
     \hline

    \end{tabular}
     }%
    \caption{Forecasting}
    \label{tab:results}
\end{table}
```

Comment: The first error here, that `\multirow` has not been defined, may be the only error that matters.  In this case, the problem is that `\multirow` isn't defined in the basic LaTeX vocabulary, but requires a package.  (I'm not sure which one offhand, but someone else will know.)  However, once that one is taken care of, most (if not all) of the others will likely disappear.  Some errors can safely be ignored, but some are truly fatal; any undefined command beginning with `\multi` is likely to proliferate more, so fix that and rerun, ignoring the rest for the moment.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You did not provide a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) (which you always should do on this site), but it seems that you need to load the `multirow` package. Also, the `\multirow` command takes three arguments: the first is to specify the number of rows the cell should span, the second takes a width (but you can use `*` to set it to the natural width of the contents). So, to solve the errors, do two things: place `\usepackage{multirow}` in your preamble and correct the two `\multirow` commands to `\multirow{4}{*}{...}`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is the one you expected!

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{adjustbox,float}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
     \centering
     \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
     \begin{tabular}{|cccccccc|}
     \hline
     \multicolumn{8}{|l|}{FORECAST 24H} \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}                                          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Model}                 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Past History} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{MSE}      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{RMSE}     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{MAE}      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{WAPE}     & MAPE     \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{MACHINE LEARNING}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{LR}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{24}            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1083220}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{581.6717} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{502.9881} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.026775} & 0.027288 \\ \cline{3-8}
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}                                          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{48}            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{955023.4} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{544.9984} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{463.4439} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.024786} & 0.025514 \\ \cline{3-8} 
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}                                          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{72}            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{902146.3} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{535.9016} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{454.1736} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.024341} & 0.025129 \\ \cline{3-8} 
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}                                          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{96}            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{901062.8} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{534.4753} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{452.8799} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.024281} & 0.025125 \\ \cline{3-8} 
     \hline

    \end{tabular}
     }%
    \caption{Forecasting}
    \label{tab:results}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note that you didn't mention about the class name what you are using, so I used the standard `book` class file.

[image]

Already `barbara beeton` and `Jasper Habicht` explained about the usage of `\multirow` in comment.

Comment: You would not need to load the `multirow` package for this answer actually.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Yes, modified it

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to TeX.SX! Let's go through the code snippet you provide. Since I don't know anything about your code and you did not provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) (which you always should do on this site), I started from scratch and just pasted your snippet into the minimal basic document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  <your code snippet>
\end{document}
```

This returned some errors, which I addressed one after another. This is always the best thing to do: Only tackle the first error, ignore the rest. Then compile again and address the next error (if any).

So, let's go through the errors that popped up for me one after another:

1. `LaTeX Error: Unknown float option 'H'`: Thie error can be solved by loading the `floats` package (you probably already loaded this package and hence did not get this error).
2. `LaTeX Error: Unknown control sequence '\resizebox'`: Thie error can be solved by loading the `graphicx` package (you probably already loaded this package and hence did not get this error).
3. `LaTeX Error: Unknown control sequence '\multirow'`: This error can be solved by loading the `multirow` package (this is the first error you got as well).
4. `Missing number, treated as zero.`: This error is due do the fact that the `\mulirow` command expects three mandatory arguments of which the first takes a number and denotes the number of rows the cell should span. The second argument takes a width, but you can also use `*` to set the width to the natural width of the cell contents. So you should use `\multirow{4}{*}{...}` in your code.

You should also consider changing your column definition to something like `|l|c|c|l|l|l|l|l|` which will allow you to remove a lot of unnecessary `\multicolumn` commands from your code. (Whether or not the use of `\resizebox` is a good idea, is another question which I won't answer here.)

The final working code is then:

```
\documentclass{article}

% LaTeX Error: Unknown float option 'H'
\usepackage{float} 

% LaTeX Error: Unknown control sequence '\resizebox'
\usepackage{graphicx} 

% LaTeX Error: Unknown control sequence '\multirow'
\usepackage{multirow} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|l|l|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{8}{|l|}{FORECAST 24H} \\
        \hline
         & Model & Past History & MSE & RMSE & MAE & WAPE & MAPE \\ \hline
        \multirow{4}{*}{MACHINE LEARNING} & \multirow{4}{*}{LR} & 24 & 1083220 & 581.6717 & 502.9881 & 0.026775 & 0.027288 \\ \cline{3-8}
         & & 48 & 955023.4 & 544.9984 & 463.4439 & 0.024786 & 0.025514 \\ \cline{3-8} 
         & & 72 & 902146.3 & 535.9016 & 454.1736 & 0.024341 & 0.025129 \\ \cline{3-8} 
         & & 96 & 901062.8 & 534.4753 & 452.8799 & 0.024281 & 0.025125 \\ \cline{3-8} 
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
    }%
    \caption{Forecasting}
    \label{tab:results}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

And its output:

[image]